# Exception handling for reading in csv

Tags: python

My program takes in input of the file name and makes some alterations to the file. In case the user enters the wrong name, I don't want my program to crash.

Currently, my code is:

```
try: 
     df = pd.read_csv('directory\\%s' % user_input)
except Exception:
     [error message]
```

For some reason, I keep getting the error message even when the file name exists. Is something wrong with my approach?

Comment: `'directory\\name' % user_input` ?? try `'directory\\%s' % user_input` instead..

Comment: ah sorry that was a typo (fixed). with %s, it sill gives the error message.

Comment: fixed? so can you [edit] your question? and try `except Exception as e:` then `print(str(e))` you'll have the exact exception message

Answer (score 4):

Whenever possible you should try to be specific with your exception handling. Your code doesn't look quite right.
    import os

```
try: 
     df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(directory, user_input))
except IOError as e:
    # print e
```

Might be what you want.

Comment: This worked. Could you explain to me what it did? Thanks

Comment: The code above catches the specific case of when you have an IOError, in which case you can handle it or keep going. Rather than attempting to join the directory and the basename of the path by myself. I used the os.path.join method, which knows about things like path separators and generates the path for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your file path is formatted wrong.

```
'directory\\%s' % user_input
```