# Is it possible to pass an extra argument to lambda function in pandas read_csv

Tags: python, pandas

I am using the `read_csv()` function from `pandas` and the option for a lambda `date_parser` function quit often and I am wondering if it is possible to pass an argument to this labda function.

This is a minimal example where I set the format_string:

```
import pandas as pd

def date_parser_1(value, format_string='%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S'):
    return pd.to_datetime(value, format=format_string)

df = pd.read_csv(file,
             parse_dates=[1], 
             date_parser=date_parser_1 #args('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')                    
            )
print(df)
```

I do know, that `pandas` has a `infer_datetime_format` flag, but this is question is only looking for a self defined `date_parser`.

Comment: What is the argument? Can you use a closure to generate the function on the fly?

Comment: I assume you raise the question as import fails. This might be caused by mixed formats.
Maybe you can review the csv file and there is also the opportunity to use  an error handler as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45575057/exception-handling-for-reading-in-csv or the "error_bad_lines=False" option in pd.read_csv() .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the magic of partial functions.

```
def outer(outer_arg):
    def inner(inner_arg):
        return outer_arg * inner_arg    
    return inner

fn = outer(5)
print(fn(3))
```

Basically you define your function inside a function and return that inner function as the result. In this case I call `outer(5)` which means I now have a function assigned to `fn` that I can call lots of times, each time it will execute the inner function, but with the `outer_arg` in the closure.

So in your case:

```
def dp1_wrapper(format_string):
    def date_parser_1(value):
        return pd.to_datetime(value, format=format_string)
    return date_parser_1


df = pd.read_csv(file,
    parse_dates=[1],
    date_parser=dp1_wrapper('%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S')
)
```

Once you know how this works, there is a shortcut utility:

```
from functools import partial 

df = pd.read_csv(file,
    parse_dates=[1],
    date_parser=partial(date_parser_1, format='%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S')
)
```

Comment: Wow. This looks simple.

Comment: There's also a built-in version of this called [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial)

Comment: @hampus-larsson I always like to tell people about partial functions manually first, because otherwise it looks like actual magic!

Comment: `from functools import partial` instead of reimplementing the same functionality?

Comment: @dpwrussell I don't agree with that sentiment. Especially, when there already is an explanation and example for just that in the documentation.

Comment: I've added it to the answer, but I still think that when exposed to this for the first time, it's good to see how this works.